# How to get "other" data from a ZF2 form once it's bound to a Doctrine 2 entity?

Tags: forms, validation, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form2

I have a form that I've created using annotations on a Doctrine 2 entity. (Yes, I know it's slow; that's how I've learned and I'm using it on legacy code. But this would probably apply with a form made from scratch anyway)

Anyway, here's the situation. The entity has pretty standard stuff for a user: name, email, sex, etc. It also has a One-To-Many property, called "Role". So I took the form that I built with the AnnotationBuilder and added a select element (named "roleId") to let the user choose the user's role. From there, once the form is validated, I then want to grab the roleId value, get the corresponding entity from the database, and then go `$user->setRole($role)`.

Here's where I get into trouble. If I use `$form->bind($user)`, and then `$form->isValid()`, when I then call `$form->getData()`, I end up with the user entity, not an array of the filtered and validated data from the form.

So how should I handle this situation? Is there some way to get a flat array of ALL of the filtered and validated data from a form once it's been bound to an entity?

Comment: After the validation you need to add: $roles = $form->get('roles')->getValue(); and futher foreach ($roles as $role) $user->addRole($role). I had the same situation, but I don´t know if I solved it right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924541/zf2-doctrine2-error-when-validate-a-collection-field-of-an-one-to-many-associ